# Sometime checkboxes in listview android doesn't work in any android devices

Tags: android, checkbox

When I am getting data from server as a list and displaying in android devices with using `Checkboxes`.

Some of `Checkboxes` are working (clickable) but some of them are not clickable sometimes.

Here is my check-box code:

```
 <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/empCheck"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txtCustNo"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
```

Here is my getView method code :

```
@Override
    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mlayouInflater.inflate(R.layout.nodel_row, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expandableIcon);
            viewHolder.checkPickupSelect = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (mGroupTaskView != null && !mGroupTaskView.isEmpty()) {
            viewHolder.checkPickupSelect.setChecked(mGroupTaskView.get(groupPosition).getRollOut().equalsIgnoreCase("B"));
        }

        if (mGroupTaskView != null && !mGroupTaskView.isEmpty()) {
            viewHolder.checkPickupSelect
                    .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            mTaskFragment.empSelected(groupPosition, child, viewHolder.checkPickupSelect.isChecked());
                        }
                    });
        }

        if (mGroupTaskView != null && !mGroupTaskView.isEmpty()) {
            if (mGroupTaskView.get(groupPosition).getRollOut().equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
                viewHolder.checkPickupSelect.setEnabled(false);
        }

        if (mGroupTaskView.get(groupPosition).getRollOut().equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
            viewHolder.checkPickupSelect.setChecked(true);
            viewHolder.checkPickupSelect.setEnabled(false);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Do you use a custom adapter? If you do, post your `getView()` implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove this two lines and it should work:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```